# WiFi stops working on Raspberry Pi when SD card reader is overclocked

Tags: pi-3b+, sd-card, wireless, overclocking

I'm having a very weird problem where if I overclock the SD card reader on my Pi 3B+ using `dtoverlay=sdhost,overclock_50=100` the wireless stops working. Raspi-config says 'No wireless interface found'.
How do I fix this?

System details:

- Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+
- Latest version of Raspberry Pi OS Lite

Comment: Are you sure that is weird?  Generally overclocking is at your own risk.  There is also a warning saying this will kill the wifi.

Comment: I haven't seen that warning before. What was weird was the 2 things which seem very unrelated to each other. The reason I'm doing this is because I'm using the Pi as a mini-NAS (I know, an SD card isn't great for it) and my R/W speeds are very bad (5mb/s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than worrying about an SD card, I moved what I wanted to serve to my network to USB flash drives. This way the system doesn't become unresponsive and/or have slow write speeds when many files are being copied to it.

Answer (score 2):

You asked how to fix the overclocking problem. I would say the solution is: don't overclock the Raspberry Pi because you are also get a warning that it may kill your WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

The speed issue is your SD card. A good card will manage 20+ MB/s at stock settings. Your bottleneck is not SDIO speed, it is the card.

WiFi is on the 2nd SDIO interface. So, you also overclocked WiFi interface when you overclocked the SD.

Maybe there is a way to set different speeds on the two interfaces, maybe there isn't.